# Selenium Error in Python - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get data from a password protected website with Selenium.
However I get stuck right in the beginning at login with the following error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

The name I use is correct for sure, I inspected the website. Including waiting time did not help either...

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from getpass import getpass



driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://clearing.apcs.at/emwebapcsem/startApp.do")

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)


# create an object for searchbox
username=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
# typte the input
username.send_keys("XXXXXX")
password.send_keys("XXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the *Benutzer* and *Passwort* field as the elements are within an `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://clearing.apcs.at/emwebapcsem/startApp.do')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[title='menu']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.loginContentBoxInput[name='username']"))).send_keys("Endre")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.loginContentBoxInput[name='password']").send_keys("Endre")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://clearing.apcs.at/emwebapcsem/startApp.do')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@title='menu']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='loginContentBoxInput' and @name='username']"))).send_keys("Endre")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='loginContentBoxInput' and @name='password']").send_keys("Endre")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: clearing]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)